# How to calculate the buffer capacity for polyprotic acids? specifically H2PO4 --- HPO42- + H30+

Tags: acid-base, reaction-mechanism, thermodynamics, equilibrium, buffer

as the title says. Is b= amount of OH-/ H3O divided by volume of buffer x change in pH wrong to use with polyprotic acids? Can I calculate the buffering capacity of a sodium phosphate buffer made up of NaH2PO4 and NaH2PO4 using this formula?

Comment: Generally, first thing is to check, if you can afford to treat it like if it were not a multiprotic acid. Typically if other pKa are far enough from the supposed pH.

Comment: phosphoric acid has 3 pkas. 2.12, 7.21, and 12.4. I'm considering the second pka and pH 7.4 can I treat it as if it isnt multiprotic?

Comment: I take it as your rhetorical question, before you will do the calculations and make the conclusion, with eventual final clarifying questions.